# How to split multiple values of a parameter in JSON response?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, web-api-testing

My JSON response has multiple values for a single attribute, as copied below.

```
{
   "version": "10.2.2.48",
   "systemMessages": [   {
      "code": -8010,
      "error": "",
      "type": "error",
      "module": "BROKER"
   }],
   "locations": [   {
      "id": "10101102",
      "name": "Bus Stop",
      "disassembledName": "Bus",
      "coord":       [
         3755258,
         4889121
      ],
      "type": "stop",
      "matchQuality": 1000,
      "isBest": true,
      "modes":       [
         1,
         5,
         11
      ],
      "parent":       {
         "id": "95301001|1",
         "name": "Sydney",
         "type": "locality"
      },
      "assignedStops": [      {
         "id": "10101102",
         "name": "Bus Stop",
         "type": "stop",
         "coord":          [
            3755258,
            4889121
         ],
         "parent":          {
            "name": "Sydney",
            "type": "locality"
         },
         "modes":          [
            1,
            5,
            11
         ],
         "connectingMode": 100
      }]
   }]
}
```

Observe that "modes" has 3 values. If I try to extract the value of modes through JsonSlurper script assertion, it gives the value as [1,5,11] and count as just 1. I want to split them into 3 array elements or variables and need the count as 3. What's the possible script assertion code?

Assertion:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def resp = messageExchange.response.responseContent;
def jsl = new JsonSlurper().parseText(resp);
def modes = jsl.locations.modes
log.info modes
log.info modes.size()
```

Result:

```
Wed Feb 13 10:50:49 AEDT 2019:INFO:[[1, 5, 11]]

Wed Feb 13 10:50:49 AEDT 2019:INFO:1
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are dealing with in this example is a shorthand version of [Groovy's spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) and your code returns a valid result. When you call `jsl.locations` you actually access a list of all locations objects (a singleton list in your example). When you call

```
jsl.locations.modes
```

you use a shorthand version of

```
jsl.locations*.modes
```

which is an equivalent of the following code:

```
jsl.locations.collect { it.modes }
```

This code means: iterate `locations` and transform a list of locations into a list of lists of modes of these locations - `[[1,5,11]]`.

Applying the correct solution depends on a few more factors. For instance, you need to consider `locations` list containing multiple locations - in this case, transformation `jsl.locations.modes` may produce a result like `[[1,5,11],[1,5,11],[2,4,9]]` - a list of 3 modes lists.

If you assume that there is always a single location returned then you can simply flatten the final list like:

```
def modes = jsl.locations.modes.flatten()
assert modes == [1,5,11]
assert modes.size() == 3
```

However, if `locations` contains another JSON object, let's say, with exactly the same modes, then it will produce a completely different result:

```
def modes = jsl.locations.modes.flatten()
assert modes == [1,5,11,1,5,11]
assert modes.size() == 6
```

In this case, it might be better to use assertions like:

```
def modes = jsl.locations.modes
assert modes == [[1,5,11],[1,5,11]]
assert modes*.size() == [3,3]
```

which means:

- `modes` stores 2 lists `[1,5,11]` and `[1,5,11]`,
- and the size of the first list is 3, and the size of the second list is also 3.

Comment: Many Thanks Szymon!
<def modes = jsl.locations.modes.flatten()> is all I need now, but your detailed explanation made me learn more about JSON assertions.